# Get value from ref - Indicates constantly Can not read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

That's how I try to get in the **ref** area. But when I try to write content into the input then when I have to show it in `console.log` it just indicates that my `mailRef` is

> Can not read property 'value' of undefined

```
import React from 'react';

class Signup extends React.Component {
    mailRef = React.createRef();

handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('heyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy');
    console.log('Submit: ' + this.mailRef.value.value);
}
..
```

html:

```
<input type="text" name="email" ref={this.mailRef} className="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
```

If I just have to write "*heyyyyyyyyy*" into `console.log` I'll get it out but as soon as I get the content I've written, it will not grab it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the declaration in the constructor like this:

```
import React from 'react';

class Signup extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.mailRef = React.createRef();  //fixed
   }

   handleSubmit = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('heyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy');
      console.log('Submit: ' + this.mailRef.current.value); //fixed
   }
```

For more information: [Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

Comment: I read myself to do just that. then it was resolved. `this.mailRef.current.value`